Mongo query with many or conditions
My question is about a query with many or conditions.
I want to get all accounts where (id = id1 and date > date1) or (id = id2 and date > date2) or (id = id3 and date > date3) etc (can be up to a 1000, maybe more)
I have compound index of id and than date
will that query work well, performance wise? Is there a better way to do it?
Im new to mongo and will be happy for any suggestions
Thank you!

Have you checked out wildcard index?

I read this just now, not sure if it can help. My fields' names don't change

It should support querying different sets of fields as demo in playground. If you have some testing environment, try to set it up and run an explain to see if it helps.

I cant set a test env with a substantial amount if data currently. But my understanding of the wildcard index is that i can index fields where the field names are unkonwn in advance. Mine are known and i added an index to them

As far as I know you cannot put 1000 fields into an index. And most likely it is not needed either. Create the index on the most common used fields. You will not gain so much if you try to add any field.

That's not what im doing. I have 2 fields: id and date (on which i have comound index) . I make a lot of or operations in my query. My question was how would it behave performance wise

Did you try running your query with explain to see if it used the index?
